# Sorting a table from row-indexed to column-indexed

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an original table constructed from values entered left-to-right, top-to-bottom.

```
0, 1, 2, 3,
4, 5, 6, 7,
8, 9, 10, 11
```

Where `COLUMNS` is equal to 4, the updated index sort (top-to-bottom, left-to-right) becomes:

```
0, 4, 8, 1,
5, 9, 2, 6,
10, 3, 7, 11
```

In other words, the item at index:1 from the original table is moved to index:4, the item at index:2 from the original table is moved to index:8, and so forth. After applying this sort, the values fill from top-to-bottom, left-to-right.

How would I phrase this sort in ES6 / Javascript?

Comment: Didn't get how it is sorted. Can you please add more description?

Comment: @RishabhDeepSingh In the original table, the value "1" is to the right of "0", and "2" is to the right of "1." So you can read the original table from left to right, top to bottom. In the updated table, "1" becomes "4", such that it would be underneath "0" in the original table.

Comment: Didn't get the part, how does 1 become 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer this code.

```js
const data = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
const COLUMNS = 4;

const result = data.map((val, index) => data[index === data.length - 1 ? index : index * COLUMNS % (data.length - 1)]);

console.log(result);
```